# Set dynamic default for django modelform foreignkey field

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to set the default value for a modelform foreignkey to the first item in the queryset.

The queryset is being dynamically generated in the forms **init** method, and is returned in order such that 95% of the time the user will select the first item.

How can I set the default value to the first item in the queryset?

I have tried this in the form init method, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
self.fields['my_foreignkey_field'].initial = self.fields['my_foreignkey_field'].queryset[0]
```

Using "set_trace" in the view, I can see that `my_form['my_foreignkey_field'].field.initial` is indeed set to the correct value, but it is not populating the select field in the template.

Here are more details from the form init method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(My_Form, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs) 
    if self.instance.some_fk_field.some_value > 0:
        self.fields['important_fk_field'].queryset = self.get_important_queryset()
        if self.instance.some_fk_field.some_value == 1:
            #set the default
            self.fields['important_fk_field'].initial = self.fields['important_fk_field'].queryset[0].pk
    else: #foreignkey should be null
        self.fields['important_fk_field'].queryset = FK_Model.objects.filter(pk=-1)  #Empty queryset
```

Comment: Can you add the full init code of the modelform?

Comment: What happens if you redeclare the whole field, passing initial into the constructor as so: `self.fields['my_foreignkey_field'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=queryset, initial=queryset[0])`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Spike.  That seems to work.  Any ideas on why my original method didn't work?  It would be a lot cleaner if I didn't have to redefine widget attributes as well.